# Can VBA code be used in PPT to paste from clipboard to PNG?

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I've tried numerous versions to get this code. This one at least errors out... I want to be in PowerPoint, Paste Special from the Clipboard to PNG.

```
Sub Test()
ActivePresentation.Slides.Paste.Shapes.PasteSpecial ppPastePNG

End Sub
```

This errors out to say

> "Invalid Request. Clipboard is empty or contains data which may not be pasted here."

The clipboard is not empty and does contain data I can paste in.

Thanks for any ideas!

Comment: Do you want export something in the presentation to PNG or do you want to import a PNG into the presentation?

Comment: I am copying items from another presentation. Then want to use Paste Special, PNG to paste them in. (Reason behind this: I lock the data of the slide, but not the background.)

Comment: The clipboard may contain data that you can paste in, but if it doesn't contain PNG data, you'll get that message.  Put the data on the clipboard then manually use PasteSpecial.  See if PNG is one of the options listed.  If not, that's your problem.

Comment: PNG is an option. That is why VBA has the code ppPastePNG. PowerPoint can convert anything into multiple formats - PNG, JPG, GIF, etc.

Comment: PNG is an option only in the sense that PowerPoint will paste it IF the other app has put PNG on the clipboard.  PowerPoint can PUT multiple formats on the clipboard, but so far as I know, won't do the conversion when it pastes.  It only takes a few seconds to perform the test I suggested.

Comment: It is though... So I copy from another ppt, go into the new deck, click Paste Special, Paste PNG. Paste Special has those options no matter what you've copied. PowerPoint does the conversion... no matter what or where you copy from.

Comment: PPT isn't converting content from the clipboard.  That's not how the clipboard works.  Any app that puts stuff ON the clipboard can put it up there in many different formats, including its own private formats.  Any app that pulls content off the clipboard will show you only the formats that it understands and can deal with when you do PasteSpecial manually.  That's why I suggested that you check there first.  If the app that you copied FROM didn't put PNG there, PowerPoint won't offer it to you.  Since you ARE seeing PNG as an option, we now know that this isn't the problem.

Comment: Have a look here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3260717/powerpoint-vba-paste-special-enhanced-metafile-bug  If PowerPoint's focus is on a pane that can't accept images, you can also get that error.  For example, if focus is on Slide pane, it should be ok.  If focus is on notes, slide sorter, thumbnails, outline or some of the other panes, you'll see the error you described.

Answer (score 1):

FYI - after much trial and error, I came up with this macro. It copies the slide content and pastes it back to the slide as PNG.

```
Sub test()
Dim sld As Slide
Dim pre As Presentation
Dim shp1 As Shape
Dim shp2 As Shape


Set pre = ActivePresentation

For Each sld In pre.Slides
    Set shp1 = sld.Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeRectangle, 0, 0, 20, 20)
    shp1.Line.Visible = msoFalse
    shp1.Fill.Transparency = 1

Set shp2 = sld.Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeRectangle, 0, 0, 20, 20)
shp2.Left = 720 - shp2.Width
shp2.Top = 540 - shp2.Width
shp2.Line.Visible = msoFalse
shp2.Fill.Transparency = 1
Next

For Each sld In pre.Slides
     sld.Shapes.Range.Cut

If sld.Shapes.Count > 0 Then
   sld.Shapes.Range.Delete
   sld.Shapes.PasteSpecial ppPastePNG
   sld.Shapes.Range.Align msoAlignCenters, msoTrue
   sld.Shapes.Range.Align msoAlignMiddles, msoTrue
End If

If sld.Shapes.Count = 0 Then
sld.Shapes.PasteSpecial ppPastePNG
sld.Shapes.Range.Align msoAlignCenters, msoTrue
sld.Shapes.Range.Align msoAlignMiddles, msoTrue
End If
Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer:

```
Set m = ActivePresentation
n = m.Slides.Count
m.Slides.Add n + 1, ppLayoutBlank
m.Slides(2).Shapes.PasteSpecial ppPastePng
```

reference page on msdn for powerpoint:
"shape" paste formats:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff745158(v=office.15).aspx

new slide layouts:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff745137(v=office.15).aspx

Alternatively if plain text is desired:

```
m.Slides.Add n + 1, ppLayoutText
m.Slides(n + 1).Shapes(2).TextFrame.TextRange.PasteSpecial (ppPasteText)
```

"textrange" pastespecial formats:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff745706(v=office.15).aspx

Or even get text into variable:

```
 myVar = m.Slides(1).Shapes(1).TextFrame.TextRange.Text
```

"textrange" text property:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff746239(v=office.15).aspx

P.S.
Lowercase is also acceptable for properties or methods, although they are all CAPITAL letters in documentation.
Brackets on function calling may be omitted as above first code block.